# Generated google-services.json is incomplete oauth_client object is missing on new added app

Tags: android, firebase

I'm facing the same issue as mentioned in the [link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2536).

Please help if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Found out why the client ID was missing.

**Android Solution**

1. You need to download the '[KeyStore](https://forums.appgyver.com/t/how-to-get-sha1-key-for-my-app/17390)' application.
2. Follow this [YouTube Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=29umXQV-SPg&list=PLd-L5s0e6eif0cu7kMuX2-mGeH7uB3QuV&index=7) to generate SHA-1 certificate fingerprint key.

<=======================================================>

**iOS Solution Steps**

1. Go to Firebase->Authentication section
2. Add Google as sign in provider

[image]

3. It will generate new file as shown below

[image]